# Unable to install Eventmachine Ruby 2.0 windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install Event Machine on Ruby 2.0 under windows 7 but I get the following error

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

:154:0,
                     from binder.cpp:20:
    eventmachine.h: At global scope:
    eventmachine.h:46:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:47:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
    [-Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:48:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:50:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:65:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:66:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:67:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:68:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [
    -Wignored-qualifiers]
    In file included from project.h:154:0,
                     from binder.cpp:20:
    eventmachine.h:103:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
    [-Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:105:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
    [-Wignored-qualifiers]
    eventmachine.h:108:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
    [-Wignored-qualifiers]
    make: *** [binder.o] Error 1

I tried using gem install eventmachine --pre but that didn't help either

Comment: install linux, seriously !!!

Answer (score -1):

i suggest you to use linux but for your question try this

```
 gem install eventmachine --pre
```

it will install eventmachine

Comment: add `gem eventmachine` in gemfile